# Number of Samples for Accurate Measure of Heavily Weighted Coin

Tags: bernoulli-process

I see articles on how to prove the "fairness" of a coin by flipping it N times. Using the estimator of true probability p=h/(h+t) along with a target max error and confidence interval, you can find the number of flips required, N.

My question is the same, except that I know the coin is heavily weighted (i.e. hardly ever appears 'heads') and I want the number of flips N to prove that the real probability of this coin is simply less than p_max.

For example, if p_max is 0.01, and I flip N=100 times and get heads 0 or even 1 time, I'm still quite uncertain that the real probability of this coin is <0.01.  If I flip 1000 times I'm a little more comfortable.  What is the theory here?

Comment: It's the same theory: only the numbers change, from an assumed probability of $0.5$ to $0.01.$

Comment: Fair enough, but how about this...  If I measure that p<0.01 with N flips, what is the probability that the TRUE probability weight of this coin was really <0.01?

Comment: That question is not addressed by the power analyses to which you allude in the question, nor is it even consistent with it.  You want a Bayesian analysis that can derive an answer from your prior distribution for $p.$

Comment: @Ryan How would you do the two-tailed analogue of calculating that probability? Your answer to that will she’s light on what you want to do, because confidence intervals don’t quite give probabilities about parameters.

Comment: Ok @whuber thanks for the tip. I'll look into that, but as you can see, I'm very new to this. If you have a resource or link to get me started in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.  Sorry and thanks again!